# TCPListener throwing Socket Exception on listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am working on a TCP Listener Service which waits for client to connect and receive files.
The following code is used to initialize TCP Listener.

```
    var listener= new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
                    listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
listener.Start();
```

Then waiting for client as

```
private void WaitForTcpClient(TcpListener listener){
    while(!listener.Pending()){
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(BeginListeningInBackground, listener);
}
```

This is the method BeginListeningInBackground.

```
private async void BeginListeningInBackground(IAsyncResult asyncResult){
    var listener = asyncResult.AsyncState as TcpListener;
    var tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);
    Task.Run(() =>
            {
                WaitForTcpClient(listener);
            });
    using (NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream()){
    //working with netStream here
    }
}
```

It was working great when I tested on my local computer but after deployment, it started giving Socket Exception. The message by socket exception was as following.
[image]
Even after catching exception, the same exception is constantly occurring. What is the cause of this exception and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The listener should always use IPAny as the listening socket.  You probably are using the loopback IP addrerss 172.0.0.1 or the old computer IP address (or Computer Name).  You could also be getting the error if you are using the wrong IP (IPV4 vs IPV6).

Comment: Listener is using the IPAddress.Any, the other property is IPAddress.IPv6Any, are you specifying I should use that one? But the problem is with connection with TCP Client so should that part not be the one causing problem?

Comment: The IP version depends on the setup of the PC.  The error indicates a connection is not occurring probably due to a route not existing between the client and server (or server to client).  Yes it is possible to have a route in one direction and not the other.  I would verify the IP address of server and Server Name.  Then try both Server IP and then Server Name in client to see if either works.  Also make sure the port number is the same on both client and server.  The port may already be in use so try a port number above 10,000.

Comment: Okay I'll check that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it is problem, but i can see that you are using `Sleep` that will block the socket operations (I/O) and it could be the reason of your exception.

try this code, i tested before.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dummy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpListener listener;
        byte[] bufferRx;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int port = 9982;
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            listener.Start();

            //Begin to start the first connection
            System.Console.WriteLine("Waitting for client");
            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(BeginListeningInBackground, listener);
        }

        private void BeginListeningInBackground(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("new for client request.");
            var listener = asyncResult.AsyncState as TcpListener;
            var tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);

            BeginToReadOnCLient(tcpClient);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Waitting for next client");
            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(BeginListeningInBackground, listener);

        }

        private void BeginToReadOnCLient(TcpClient client)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Initi Rx on Client");

            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            bufferRx = new byte[10];
            ns.BeginRead(bufferRx, 0, 10, ReadFromClientStream, ns);// (BeginListeningInBackground, listener);
        }

        private void ReadFromClientStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Read Data from client. DATA:[" + System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bufferRx) + "]");
            bufferRx = new byte[10];
            ns.BeginRead(bufferRx, 0, 10, ReadFromClientStream, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using your code to use to accept connections requests and read socket client in asynchronous ways, without use `Sleeps`.

1. Start Socket Server and invoke an asynchronous method to accept connections (`BeginListeningInBackground`).
2. Into `BeginListeningInBackground` the `TCPClient` socket is created (`EndAcceptTcpClient`) and start to read, in asynchronous way, check the method `BeginToReadOnCLient(tcpClient);`.
3. After accept the the connections the `TcpListener` will be waiting for another connection: `listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(BeginListeningInBackground, listener);`.

Into the method `BeginToReadOnCLient` the operation to read is asynchronous, usin the `NetworkStream`:

```
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
bufferRx = new byte[10];
ns.BeginRead(bufferRx, 0, 10, ReadFromClientStream, ns);
```

`ReadFromClientStream` *has a sample logic to read the data*, you must implement the correct logic to read the information according with the communication protocol.

**IMPORTANT**: Read about how to use these asynchronous operations in `NetworkStream` to avoid exception at the moment of: Stop TcpListener, close a client Connection, send or read information and how many bytes have been received/read.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I read an article where they used `Thread.Sleep()` if listener did not have pending connections. It worked well on local machine as well as another testing server. I did some research and found that it may be cause of not closing `TCPClient` by the use of `using` statement with `EndAcceptTcpClient`.