# Networkstream multiple threads and transferring data

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, tcp, networkstream

I have a application that uses a Networkstream to communicate with a server. Reading and writing takes place on two different threads. One thread is always listening for data coming from the server and the other thread writes data to the stream to send a request. The server then processes the data and then sends back a order number, but since I am writing and reading on two threads I can´t read on the thread on which I initially send the data to the sever.

My Problem is that I create a listviewitem for each request I send to the server and I somehow need to identify the listviewitem that corresponds to the received order number.

```
private void SendCheckoutData()
    {
        //Start sending data
        manager.SendInt(TableId);
        Thread.Sleep(80);
        manager.SendInt(ClientId);
        Thread.Sleep(80);
        manager.SendInt(ListViewCheckoutTable.Items.Count);
        Thread.Sleep(80);
        manager.SendInt(GetCombinedPrice());
        Thread.Sleep(80);

        int NumberOfItems = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < ListViewCheckoutTable.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            OrderMenuItem item = (OrderMenuItem)ListViewCheckoutTable.Items.GetItemAt(i);
            manager.SendInt(item.Id);
            Thread.Sleep(80);
            manager.SendInt(item.Quantity);
            Thread.Sleep(80);
            NumberOfItems += item.Quantity;
        }

        int OrderNumber; //The variable I somehow need to assign the value to

        ListViewPendingOrders.Items.Add(new PendingOrderMenuItem { OrderNumber = OrderNumber, Quantity = NumberOfItems, TotalPrice = GetCombinedPrice() });
    }
```

**TCPManager**

```
class TCPManager
{
    private readonly string ip;
    private readonly int port;

    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream stream;

    Task ListenerTask;
    CancellationTokenSource cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public TCPManager(string ip, int port)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
        stream = client.GetStream();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        cancelToken.Cancel();

        while (!ListenerTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }

    public void ReadData()
    {
        ListenerTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                while (!stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                StartNewTask(GetInt());
            }

        }, cancelToken.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private void StartNewTask(int request)
    {
        switch (request)
        {
            case RequestIds.REQUEST_ORDERNUMBER:

                break;

            case RequestIds.REQUEST_ORDER_COMPLETED:
                break;
        }
    }
public int GetInt()
        {
            byte[] bData = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            stream.Read(bData, 0, bData.Length);
            int Data = BitConverter.ToInt32(bData, 0);

            return Data;
        }
```

Comment: Avoid using Sleeps at the moment to use  Socket, it could block the I/O operations.  Instead of it, use NetworkStream with its asynchronous methods, to read and write. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966108/tcplistener-throwing-socket-exception-on-listener-endaccepttcpclientasyncresult/52998361#52998361

Comment: its is not  best prctice but you could make your class a singelton and create an instance from other classes to access it